# If I delete a row in database-mysql, exist some function in php that reorderthe ids?

Tags: php, mysql

If I delete a row in database-mysql, exist some function in php that reorder the ids?

like eg: have ids (1,2,3,4,5)
i delete the 3
the ids become (1,2,4,5)
so a function reorder() make:  (1,2,3,4)

I try google it, but didnt find. Any help pls,

Comment: (Duplicate is about sqlserver, but the explanations given in there why you should not attempt to do this in the first place, apply here as well.)

Comment: What do you mean by "reorder"? The given expected result changes the IDs, which (in a setup with foreign keys) has severe consequences

Comment: Agreed, this task is both completely unnecessary and introduces all kinds of problems that you don't need. Why exactly do you (think you) want to do this?

Comment: @CBroe thank u, i wont do this so.

Comment: @NicoHaase was to take the number of the row correctly, and I thought that would be nice have the ids in order cause i deleted one isnt?  but that's fine

Comment: you don't mean "in order" (because even with the gap they are still ordered small->large), you mean "consecutive" (i.e. without gaps). If you want to do that, have a separate column in the table for storing the consecutive list of numbers, which is nothing to do with the real IDs - and is presumably just used for some kind of display purpose. Or on newer versions of mysql you can generate such a list on-demand using [row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) in your select query